# Trigger change and selection in select2 populated by ajax

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I m populating my `select2` using ajax with `processResults` function as in this code,

```
function PopulateSelect2(sqlclass, ControlID, PlaceHolder) {
$('#' + ControlID).select2({
    placeholder: PlaceHolder,
    allowClear: true,
    theme: "bootstrap",
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Web_Services/Common/Controllers.asmx/populateCtls",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //delay: 250,
        data: JSON.stringify({ selector: sqlclass, subselector: '' }),
        processResults: function (data) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d);
            console.log(parsed)
            return {
                results: parsed
            };
        }
    },
});}
```

and I call this function in this way,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                PopulateSelect2("ddl_occupation", "AddrStateID", "Select")
            });
```

I am trying to set the value after by triggering change but its not working

I tried the following,

```
$('#AddrStateID').val(4).trigger('change.select2');
```

I managed to trigger selection inside the list but without showing the value in the`select`element control using this code

```
$("#AddrStateID").select2("trigger", "select", {
                    data: { id: "4" }
                })
```

**is there a way to trigger the selection and show the result in the `select` control?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in i worked around it by pre-populating my `select` control by `ajax` call but not by using `select2 - ajax call`

I added the following attributes to each `select` control

```
parent="" param="" child="" placeholder="" aval=""
```

Where,

`parent:` represents the parent id selector,
`param:` represents the control's data parameter that I use for `ajax` call,
`child:` represents the control's child control id selector,
`placeholder:` represents the control's placeholder,
`aval:` represents the control's assigned value in case wanted to be populated and selected because I use my form for storing data and reading data as well.

in the following example I have 3 `select` cascade controls.

```
<div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-grobtn row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File Grobtn</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select id="GpId" style="width: 100%"
                                    class="form-control populate" name="GpId" parent="" param="ddl_btnldgp" child="#CatId"
                                    placeholder="File Grobtn..."
                                    aval="">
                                    <option></option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-grobtn row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File Category</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select id="CatId" style="width: 100%"
                                    class="form-control populate" name="CatId" parent="#GpId" param="ddl_btnldcat"
                                    placeholder="Select File Category..."
                                    child="#CatDtlId" aval="">
                                    <option></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-grobtn row">
                            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File Type</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select id="CatDtlId" style="width: 100%"
                                    class="form-control populate" parent="#CatId" param="ddl_btnldcatdtl" child=""
                                    placeholder="Select File Type..."
                                    aval="">
                                    <option></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="btn" class="btn cUpldBtn btn-success" type="button">
                    Assign</button>
```

And Are being populated using this function

```
  function populateddl(ctl) {
var $this = $(ctl);
var parent, param, child, aval
parent = $this.attr('parent');
placeholder = $this.attr('placeholder');
child = $this.attr('child');
$(child).prop("disabled", true);
param = $this.attr('param');
aval = $this.attr('aval');
if (!parent) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Web_Services/Common/Controllers.asmx/populateCtls",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj = {
            selector: param,
            subselector: null
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data.d);
            $this.html('').append('<option>')
            $(child).prop("disabled", true)
            $this.select2({
                data: jsonData,
                placeholder: $this.attr('PlaceHolder'),
                allowClear: true,
                theme: "bootstrap"
            });
            if (aval) { $this.val(aval).trigger('change'); $this.attr('aval',''); }
        },
    })
}
$this.change(function () {
    if ($this.val() && child) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Web_Services/Common/Controllers.asmx/populateCtls",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj = {
                selector: $(child).attr('param'),
                subselector: $this.val()
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {                
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(data.d);
                $(child).html('').append('<option>')
                $(child).prop("disabled", false)
                $(child).select2({
                    data: jsonData,
                    placeholder: $(child).attr('PlaceHolder'),
                    allowClear: true,
                    theme: "bootstrap"
                });
                if ($(child).attr('aval')) { $(child).val($(child).attr('aval')).trigger('change'); $(child).attr('aval', ''); }
            },
        })
    } else {
        $(child).html('').append('<option>').prop("disabled", true).trigger('change');
    }
})}
```

Only parents (including childs that are parent to sub select controls) are called using `function populateddl(ctl)`

in this example I populate as following,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        populateddl('#GpId');
        populateddl('#CatId');
    })
```

In order to assign values, I need to populate and select the value afterwords for child controls,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $('#GpId').val(1).attr('aval', '1').trigger('change', 'select2');
            $('#CatId').val(2).attr('aval', '2').trigger('change', 'select2');
            $('#CatDtlId').val(1).attr('aval', '1').trigger('change', 'select2');
            return false;
        })
    })
```